Covering an open garage vent and painting the garage
First time home buyer trying to learn and be handy here. We just moved into a 2 storey TH with a single car garage. It is pretty spacious for being listed as a single car garage but the previous owners did not care for it at all. It had open vents with pillows stuffed in them. I got a handyman to remove the pillows and cover the vent with drywall - I'm concerned that I made the wrong call here. Should I have filled in with insulation and then covered with drywall? Secondly, the walls are unfinished and very yellow. I'm assuming that's from the drywall aging over the years. Can I paint over this or does it need some prep?

PIcs here will help. Are you speaking of vents in the exterior walls of the garage and you just had drywall installed over the holes?

Ventilation is usually important, if done right, but without pictures/more information, we can't tell.

What do you mean by "open vents?"

The open vent was inside the garage - in the ceiling. It looked like someone had cut out a vent hole to heat the garage but no air ducts were connected to it. So the previous owners stuffed a pillow in there..
